# MetaMask no longer injects web3 error message

Tags: web3js

Busy coding a very simple front end of a simple smart contract with the following code:

```
var web3;
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); //check for metamark if cant find 
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
}
```

MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3

Ive had a look at the link, but cannot figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask deprecated `web3` and `window.web3` variables. Try using from now on `window.ethereum` which means your code will have to look like this now:

```
var web3;
if (window.ethereum) {
    web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
}
```